# What is the HTML <label> tag used for?

Tags: html

I've seen code like:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label><br/>
```

What is the `<label>` tag being used for?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: Have you read any kind of documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use <label>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636502/why-use-label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html `<label>` tag creates a label for an `<input>` element. When the `<label>` element is clicked, it toggles the control for the `input` element. For example, the `label` for an `<input>` element with `type="text"` will create focus on the `<input>` element when clicked. For the label to work, its `for` attribute must equal the id of the `<input>` element it is labeling.

For more information, read this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 2):

In a form, you generally have input controls like text boxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, select elements, etc. These often have display text to indicate what is being input. The `<label>` tag links this the display text to the input control so clicking on the display name will activate an `onclick` for the form control.

The MDN link provided by Felix King has a lot of info, but this is the relevant bit for why these exist and are used:

> When a `<label>` is clicked or tapped, and it is associated with a form control, the resulting `click` event is also raised for the associated control.

- Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 0):

The `<label>` tag allows you to label and describe an `<input>` element in a form.  The `for` attribute allows you to specify the `id` of the `<input>` element it describes.