# Why am I getting this error The value of the for attribute of the label element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control

Tags: html, css

I keep getting one error when trying to validate my HTML, I will post my code and a clip of the error below. Line 67 in the screen capture of the error is the line above the first radio button.

```
    <!-- donate page -->
    <section class = "blog container">
      <div class = "title">
         <h2>Donate</h2>
         <div>
            <h2>Donate</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="donate">Give to the American Foundation for Suicide Prevention</h2>
      <p class = "text">Established in 1987, the American Foundation for Suicide Prevention (AFSP) is a voluntary health organization that gives those affected by suicide a nationwide community empowered by research, education and advocacy to take action against this leading cause of death.</p>      
      <h2 class="donate">Why Give to AFSP?</h2>
      <p class = "text">Led by CEO Robert Gebbia and headquartered in New York, and with a public policy office in Washington, D.C., AFSP has local chapters in all 50 states with programs and events nationwide. AFSP celebrates 30 years of service to the suicide prevention movement. Learn more about AFSP in its <a href="https://annual2020.afsp.org/pdfs/AFSP-2020AnnualReport-web.pdf">latest Annual Report</a>, and join the conversation on suicide prevention by following AFSP on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/AFSPnational">Facebook</a>, <a href="https://twitter.com/afspnational">Twitter</a>, <a href="https://www.instagram.com/afspnational/">Instagram</a>, and <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/AFSPNational">YouTube</a>.</p>
      <form id="donationInfo">
         <table class="center">
            <tr>
               <td><label for="title">Title:</label>
                  Mr.<input type="radio" name="title" tabindex="-1">
                  Mrs.<input type="radio" name="title">
                  Ms.<input type="radio" name="title">
                  Dr.<input type="radio" name="title">
               </td>
               <td><label for="fname">First Name:</label><input type="text" id="fname" tabindex="2" size="20" maxlength="20"></td>
               <td><label for="lname">Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="lname" tabindex="3" size="25" maxlength="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="email" id="email" tabindex="4" size="25"></td>
               <td><label for="date">Date:</label><input type="date" id="date" tabindex="5" size="25"></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <label for="phonetype">Phone Type:</label>
                  <select id="phonetype">
                     <option value="C">Cell</option>
                     <option value="H">Home</option>
                     <option value="W">Work</option>
                     <option value="O">Other</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td><label for="telephone">Phone Number:</label><input type="tel" id="telephone" tabindex="7" size="25"></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><label for="amount">Donation Amount:</label><input type="number" id="amount" tabindex="8"></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><label for="ccNumber">Credit Card Number:</label><input type="text" id="ccNumber" tabindex="9" size="19"></td>
               <td><label for="security">Security Code:</label><input type="text" id="security" tabindex="10" size="4"></td>
               <td><label for="expiration">Expiration:</label><input type="text" id="expiration" tabindex="11" size="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Agree to Terms:</td>
               <td>Yes <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Yes" tabindex="12" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
                   No <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="No" tabindex="13" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
               </td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <br/> 
      </form>
   </section>
    <!-- end of donate page -->
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help! It is very much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click on that label?

Comment: Label is just there to label what the user will be selecting as there title

Comment: Then remove the `for="title"` from the label tag and your error should go away. [Good info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636502/why-use-label).

Answer (score 0):

See for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> To associate the  with an  element, you need to give the  an id attribute. The  then needs a for attribute whose value is the same as the input's id.

Your label has a for attribute with value title but there is no input element with an id of title.

Maybe you are thinking of putting a label on each of the following inputs which have type=radio? Each would need to have its own id in that case.