# what was basic need for for attribute in the label and input tag

Tags: html

```html
<body>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
      <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
      <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
      <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
```

what was the important role for the label 'for' attribute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use <label>?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636518/2820150)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use <label>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636502/why-use-label)

Answer (score 0):

According to w3school, The `for` attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to. So when the user clicks the label, the browser will pass the signal to the input element defined at the `for` attribute.

[Take a look at this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)